# Is pre-release versioning possible in nuget

Tags: versioning, nuget

According to the [documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Reference/Versioning), pre-release versioning is supported, with an example given of:

> Within the NuSpec file, specify the version in the  element
>
> ```
> <version>1.0.1-alpha</version>
> ```

I am building from a .nuspec file; if I include this line *verbatim*, then run (at the package manager console):

> PM> nuget pack "Nuget\protobuf-net.nuspec"

then I get a bit fat error:

```
Attempting to build package from 'protobuf-net.nuspec'.
NuGet.exe : Input string was not in a correct format.
At line:1 char:6
+ nuget <<<<  pack "Nuget\protobuf-net.nuspec"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Input string wa...correct format.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

If, however, I just use `<version>1.0.1</version>` and run exactly the same command, then I get:

```
Attempting to build package from 'protobuf-net.nuspec'.
Successfully created package 'C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net.1.0.1.nupkg'.
```

And indeed, it has built correctly. My NuGet Package Manager reports version 2.0.30625.9003.

So: am I doing something wrong? or did they break something?

Comment: Does the same happen when you use the nuget.exe commandline outside of the NuGet Package Manager Console?

Comment: I just did this without any problem with nuget 2.0.30619.9000. If you run `nuget help` what's the version it prints out at the top?

Comment: @vsjones `NuGet Version: 1.5.21005.9019` - that sounds oddly low...?

Comment: @vsjones hmmm... it could just be my Nuget.CommandLine has got out of step... in which case... my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NuGet Version: 1.5.21005.9019

Semantic versioning was [introduced in nuget 1.6](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-1.6). Time for an upgrade. You can use `nuget update -self` to update right from the command line.

Comment: Yep; as simple as that; `NuGet.CommandLine` was out of date, and somehow wasn't showing for update. I'm not going to over-analyse why - uninstalling and reinstalling `NuGet.CommandLine` fixet it, cheers.